# Compute the following expression $\Sigma {100}{k=1} [k*(-1)^k]$.

Tags: summation, proof-writing, summation-method

I honestly have no idea how to format this.
Anyways, I did this so far using the properties listed in my notes. I am pretty sure it is wrong, and if it isn't, where would I go from here?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

We need $$\sum_{r=1}^{2n}r(-1)^r=\sum_{r=1}^n(2r)-\sum_{r=1}^n(2r-1)=\sum_{r=1}^n\{2r-(2r-1)\}=\sum_{r=1}^n1=?$$

Comment: I am completely lost as to what you did here.

Comment: @CraigD, Please find the updated answer

Comment: The last one would be equal to 1n right? But how did you get from the original question, to your starting point in your answer?

Comment: ohh! i understand your solution now. Thank you!